# Text rendered incorrectly on iOS 7

Tags: ios7

this is my first question on Stackoverflow, so I hope I'm doing things right. 
I'm relatively new to iOS Development and have a text rendering problem on iOS 7. As you can see from the screenshot linked below some of the quotes are not rendered correctly.

http://s8.postimg.org/qv3unsuf9/Bildschirmfoto_2014_02_27_um_10_15_10.png

The problem only occurs on iOS 7 and both simulator and hardware devices. Any ideas?

Update: The following code is used to display the dialog:

```c
NSString *title = @"\"Come\" \"to\" ...";
NSString *message = @"... \"the\" \"dark\" \"side\"";
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ja" otherButtonTitles:@"Nein", nil];
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: This might happen on the simulator due to resulotion differences of your screen and the real device resolution but on a real device this should not happen especially with the native UIAlertView message

Comment: The simulator quality was my first guess too, but it happens also on iPad 2 and iPad 3.